# Set a property of a user control from repeater databound data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a user control inside of a repeater that is being bound by a sqldatasource. I get the following error: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control. **EDIT:** NEVERMIND Egg on my face. I was getting this databind error because I was binding it somewhere else in an effort to troubleshoot my real problem from last friday but I forgot about it.

**WHAT MY REAL PROBLEM IS:** The usercontrol is getting bound before the properties get set so it appears as if they are never set. When stepping through I see that they get on the property is hit before the set on the property is hit. For example if I put  <%# EVal("Address_ID") %> before the user control I will see the ID displayed but then the user control will display an emptydatatemplate because it is being passed the ID of 0.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlFacilityAddresses" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SP_Facility_GetAddresses" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Trustaff_ESig2 %>">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Facility_ID" DbType="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterAddresses" DataSourceID="sqlFacilityAddresses" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <Select:Address ID="AddressControl" runat="server"  AddressID='<%# EVal("Address_ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could handle the repeater's [ItemDataBound-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) in codebehind, get a reference to the UserControl via [Item.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.findcontrol.aspx) and set the property according to the [Item.DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.dataitem.aspx) object and your column `Address_ID`.

For example(debug to see if the type of your dataitem is really DataRowView):

```
Sub repeaterAddresses_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    ' This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
    ' Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or _
        (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        Dim addressControl as AddressControl = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("AddressControl", AddressControl)
        addressControl.AddressID = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)("Address_ID").ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Walrus: So why don't you bind your usercontrol from the repeater's ItemDataBound-event as i've suggested? You should expose a function in your control to trigger whatever your usercontrol does(f.e. `DataBind`) and call that from itemdatabound after you've set the AddressID.

Comment: I have done this in the repeater itemdatabound and it does not change my results. The user control is being bound before the property is being set. I even tried adding addresscontrol.databind() after the addressid is set in the itemdatabound event. Do you have any other idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `DataBinder.Eval` instead of `Eval` would help?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does your Address UC look like? You can use your AddressID property to do this: e.g.

```
 private bool _AddressID;
    public bool AddressID
    {
        get { return _AddressID; }
        set
        {
            if (_AddressID != value)
            {
                //addressid is changed
                 _AddressID = value;
                ReloadMyUC();
            }
        }
    }
```

The ReloadMyUC method does the job of getting data and rebinding the UC.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out. First I changed the repeater event to itemcreated instead of itemdatabound but then the repeater was being databound before the event that was resetting the page was being executed which resulted in a 0 ID being sent to my address user control. What I ended up doing was creating a boolean value for the class page setting it to true on the user control raised event this way when it went through the repeater itemcreated event the first time it wouldn't error out and when it went through the second time it would work correctly. This is probably not a best practices way of accomplishing this result but it works.